# converting an operation on multiple arguments into an operation on a list

Tags: map, variable, sequence

Let's say I have an operation like

```
Intersection[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -9}, SameTest -> (Abs[#1] == Abs[#2] &)]
```

but the arguments are being handed to me in the form of a list like

```
a={{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -9}};
```

How do I pass `a` to the `Intersection` function above?

```
Intersection[a, SameTest -> (Abs[#1] == Abs[#2] &)]
```

doesn't work and neither does

```
Apply[Intersection[#, SameTest -> (Abs[#1] == Abs[#2] &)] &, a]
```

What should I be doing?

Comment: Have a look at `Sequence`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SlotSequence` (`##`) and `Apply` (`@@`)

```
Intersection[##, SameTest -> (Abs[#1] == Abs[#2] &)] & @@ {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -9}}
```

It could be useful to inspect what following lines do:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, -3}, {-1, -2, -9}};
Sequence @@ a
## & @@ a
## & @ a
Sequence @ a
# & @@ a
# & @ a
```

Comment: This works as, per the suggestion of b.gatessucks, does `a2 = Apply[Sequence, a]; Intersection[a2, SameTest -> (Abs[#1] == Abs[#2] &)]`